# How to fix leaking this in constructor

Tags: memory-leaks, pmd, resource-leak

i have a class

```
class Foo { 
   private static Foo foo_obj = null;

   public Foo() {
       if (foo_obj == null) {
           foo = this;
       }
   }
}
```

I get a warning about leaking this, how would i go about fixing it.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to use the singleton pattern.  It's an odd way of doing it though and doesn't work.  Because each time Foo() gets instantiated, you create a new one. Why not use a more traditional approach like:

```
class Foo { 
   private static Foo foo_obj = new Foo();
   private Foo() {}
   public static Foo getInstance() { return Foo(); }
}
```

There are [many variations of this pattern on wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern).